Wind tunnel simulation (laminar flow)
I’m having some troubles with smoke simulations in Blender.

The one you can see here was made by Kev Ryan in Houdini, and I wanted to know if you think it is possible to recreate the same effect in Blender.
I’m having a lot of trouble creating such a non-turbolent smoke (laminar flow).
Thank you all in advance for helping me out

I've never seen laminar flow made inside of Blender, I would guess it's not achievable with the native physics simulation tools. It may be possible with geometry nodes, but it would be quite a complex task.

It seems to me I didnt read your Q carefully ... you are asking how to achieve non-turbulent (lines) smoke, right? If so, here is edit ...
Smoke sim
Simple example that works for me ...

Small Plane with Array modifier set as Flow > Inflow, Heat > 0

Cube set as Domain, Border Collisions check all without Left&Right

Sphere set as Effector> Colider

add object Force > Wind, Shape > Plane, Strengh > 4?



If sim generates gaps in smoke lines encrease Time Steps Maximum (here set to 8)


Notes ...
I'm not sure if Blender calculates back-flip turbulence ... I missed them here ... but in this case it does something what I would call like that ...

Your reference doesnt seem to highlights this effect anyway so I guess not an issue here.
Another test: Here the wind is set probably too high, so you can see fluffy steps, so more subframes - more time to bake :)

Another option
Probably too complicated and not finished now, thanks to some issues (bugs) - Fluid sim as Guide for Liquid Domain - with zero gravity you can bake liquid sim to be used as Guide > Domain for final smoke sim. The purpose of this version was to get "missing" back-flip turbulences, but I don't think there are any, so probbaly I will delete this part keep it focused :)

It does quite nice effect and it works for my quick test...


... but for example with lines it is crashing for some reason (I will have to check it why). Also Guide Domain feature seems to be bugged ... it works for Replay or for Modular bake type, but it is ignored when I try to Bake smoke sim as All, hm.

This actually looks really good, but I like the effect the smoke creates, just for the looks actually
